# I have a problem to solve in powerapps dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, formula, powerapps

What's up guys!! I made an application and in this application I register an RFID of cotton bales. It contains a selection menu in which I have as an item a sequence of numbers from 1 to 500 that is the identification of the bale. The problem is: when adding the bale and the RFID, I want that bale number to leave my selection menu, so that the next bale read will be the next number. Any formula idea to solve this problem?
Note: (these RFID reads are going to a list in sharepoint and my selection menu has the formula "sequence(500;1;1)").

I've tried making check buttons to show the sequence number in the selection menu, I've tried making filters with forall and conditions with removeif, but I don't think I'm knowing how to manipulate the syntaxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of ways to approach this problem:

1. Store the initial 1-500 numbers in a collection and remove one by one after processing a bale
2. Filter the sequence to numbers that do not appear in the SharePoint list
3. Use a flow to pre-populate the SharePoint list with the items numbered 1-500 and only toggle a field when the bale is processed. Use the same filter in the dropdown.

Also, I recommend familiarizing yourself with the [different types of properties and formulas that exist in PowerApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-formulas-in-depth). You see there are so-called 'Behaviour' formulas that perform some action and others that return values. The things you've tried seem to be mixing the two, which typically doesn't work. Filtering is non-behaviour, so you can't use ForAll() or RemoveIf() in this context.

Comment: Right!! I started using power apps this Sunday hehehe So I don't really understand what you said. Could you help me to run this? I have a list in sharepoint that contains 3 columns: Date and time, Bale and RFID. In my Powerapps I have a screen that contains a dropdown menu and text input. Could you help me with what to do so that when the user selects bale 1 and its respective RFID, the next time he registers the bale, bale 1 is no longer in this drop-down menu? Note: This "project" is just to understand how powerapps works and I found this problem.

Comment: Ok, so why don't you add a Yes/No column 'Processed' to your SharePoint to track if the bale has already been selected (approach 3)? For your dropdown, use Filter(BalesDataSource,Not(Processed)). When a bale is processed, update it with Patch(BalesDataSource,LookUp(BalesDataSource,Bale=<<here goes the currently processed bale number>>),{ Processed: true })

Comment: I understood. I hadn't thought of it that way and I think it will work. But I have 2 doubts: Where do I put this patch formula... and where do I have to put the number is the user who will have to choose from the drop-down menu. How will this verification be done? Do you have another way to contact us so we can exchange an idea?

Comment: I'd rather we kept the conversation here. I'm not sure it's OK with StackOverflow to change channels and it can also be helpful for other users. So, when you finish processing a bale, I guess you click or press some button. Put the Patch formula into the button's OnSelect property. In the formula the number should replace the <<>> part

Comment: I had to go on a trip, so I didn't respond anymore. But I did all the procedure you gave me and it worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you very much, @mmikesy90!!